# ESP-NOW communication MAC adress fail

Tags: protocols, esp32

I have a problem regarding the ESP-NOW communication between ESP32 boards. I have a simple sender/receiver code. The problem I have is regarding the MAC address. If I use a broadcast address 0xFF 0xFF... I get the Delivery success message, but If I use the receiver's MAC address I get Delivery Fail. I triple-checked the MAC address but it still doesn't work. Can you guys help me with this?

Sender Code:

```c
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

// REPLACE WITH YOUR RECEIVER MAC Address
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x10, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0x33, 0xF5};

// Structure example to send data
// Must match the receiver structure
typedef struct struct_message {
  char a[32];
  int b;
  float c;
  bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;

// callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success"
                                                : "Delivery Fail");
}

void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for Send CB to
  // get the status of Trasnmitted packet
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);

  // Register peer
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 0;
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;

  // Add peer
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Set values to send
  strcpy(myData.a, "THIS IS A CHAR");
  myData.b = random(1, 20);
  myData.c = 1.2;
  myData.d = false;

  // Send message via ESP-NOW
  esp_err_t result =
      esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *)&myData, sizeof(myData));

  if (result == ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Sent with success");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending the data");
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

Receiver Code:

```c
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

// Structure example to receive data
// Must match the sender structure
typedef struct struct_message {
  char a[32];
  int b;
  float c;
  bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t *mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
  Serial.print("Bytes received: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("Char: ");
  Serial.println(myData.a);
  Serial.print("Int: ");
  Serial.println(myData.b);
  Serial.print("Float: ");
  Serial.println(myData.c);
  Serial.print("Bool: ");
  Serial.println(myData.d);
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
}

void loop() {}
```

I want to see that the message is sent successfully all the time.